# Not able to iterate list of object in jstl jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am creating web app using spring boot and jsp.
The JSP page is just showing data which i am showing set in firm object.
I am trying to fetch values from java object in c:foreach but every time getting exception  every time i hit localhost to open user page.

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [text] not found on type [java.lang.String]

Controller class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.model.ListModel;
import com.model.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView user() {
        User user = new User();
        List<ListModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        ListModel ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s1");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s2");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        user.setFavoriteFrameworks(modelList);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user", "command", user);
        return modelAndView;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("favoriteFrameworks") User 
user,BindingResult bindingResul, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
    model.addAttribute("password", user.getPassword());
    model.addAttribute("address", user.getAddress());
    model.addAttribute("receivePaper", user.isReceivePaper());
    List<ListModel> modelList = user.getFavoriteFrameworks();
    for(ListModel ll : modelList){
        System.out.println(ll.getText());
    }
    model.addAttribute("favoriteFrameworks", 
user.getFavoriteFrameworks());
    return "users";
}

    @ModelAttribute("webFrameworkList")
    public List<ListModel> getWebFrameworkList() {
        return getModel();
    }

    private List<ListModel> getModel() {

        List<ListModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        ListModel ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s1");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s2");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s3");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        ls = new ListModel();
        ls.setText("s4");
        ls.setSelcted(true);
        modelList.add(ls);
        return modelList;
    }
}
```

JSP page view

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>User Information</h2>
  <form:form method = "POST" action = "/users">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "username">User Name</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path = "username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "password">Age</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path = "password" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "address">Address</form:label></td>
           <td><form:textarea path = "address" rows = "5" cols = "30" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "receivePaper">Subscribe Newsletter</form:label></td>
           <td><form:checkbox path = "receivePaper" /></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "favoriteFrameworks">Favorite Web Frameworks</form:label></td>
          <!--  <td><form:checkboxes items = "${webFrameworkList}" path = "favoriteFrameworks" /></td>  -->

                <c:forEach items="${webFrameworkList} " var="department">
                            <tr><td>${department.text}</td></tr> 
                        <!--    <tr><td><form:checkbox
                                    path="favoriteFrameworks" value='${department.text}' checked='${department.selcted}' />${department.text}</td></tr>  -->

                </c:forEach>

        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td colspan = "2">
              <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>  
  </form:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have incorrectly set `webFrameworkList` attribute you're trying to iterate over. The exception is telling you that it can't find a `getText()` method on the `department` var defined in the jsp (which, according to the exception message, is a `String` and not your `ListModel`).

Consider eliminating the annotated `@ModelAttribute` method and instead setting the model attribute in the `ModelAndView user()` method.

```
...

ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user", "command", user);
modelAndView.addObject("webFrameworkList", getModel());

return modelAndView;
```

**Edit**

Regarding the comment about form submission, the post handler method `addUser` specifies

```
@ModelAttribute("favoriteFrameworks") User
```

but the form doesn't have a `modelAttribute` defined.

So there are two problems here.

1. `favoriteFrameworks` is a `List`, not a `User`.
2. The form doesn't specify it anyway

Change the post handler's signature to

```
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult bindingResul, ModelMap model)
```

Then change the `form` opening tag to

```
<form:form method = "POST" action = "/users" model attribute="user">
```

Comment: OI did that now the next problem happening that it is not sending checkboxes selected value on post this is null List<ListModel> modelList = user.getFavoriteFrameworks();